# How to toggle MudMenu visibility manually, when it doesn't disappear automatically?

Tags: blazor, webassembly, mudblazor

We use a MudMenu for user image upload. There are two entries called "Upload image" and "Clear image". To be able to use this line:

```
<InputFile accept=".png, .jpeg" hidden id="uploadUserImage" OnChange="@Entity.UploadImageWebCmd.WebExecuteP" />
```

... we use  as child content. There is no MudMenutItem, because you can't use "for" with it.

```
<MudMenu>
  <ActivatorContent>
  <LSFSCachedImage Path="@(Entity.User.Value.Picture.Value?.ToString() ?? "images/defaultUser.png")" Width="90" />
  </ActivatorContent>
    <ChildContent>
      <label for="uploadUserImage" 
      class="
      mud-list-item 
      mud-list-item-gutters
      mud-list-item-clickable 
      mud-ripple 
      mud-list-item-text 
      mud-typography 
      mud-typography-body1">
      <div class="mud-list-item-text">
      <p class="mud-typography mud-typography-body1">
      @RC("Button_UploadImage_Content")
      </p>
      </div>
      </label>
      <MudMenuItem 
      Command=@Entity.ClearImageCommand 
      Disabled=@Entity.ClearImageCommand.Disabled>
      @RC("Button_ClearImage_Content")
      </MudMenuItem>
    </ChildContent>
</MudMenu>
```

It works, but the only problem is, that the MudMenu does not disappear, after clicking on "Upload Image".

I tried to get rid of it by using JavaScript and I tried:

```
$(".mud-popover-provider").remove();
```

I also tried "display: none", but in both cases the MudMenu is totally broken afterwards, until I reload the web app.

If someone could help me to solve this issue as simple as possible, I would be very grateful!

Comment: This is the kind of risks you get from not using a component for its purpose. Using JS is tricky with element being handled trough the Blazor/c# logic. I would advise to look for a suitable component or create one. That being said you can get a reference of your component with `@ref` and calling [CloseMenu()](https://mudblazor.com/api/menu#methods) should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks a lot!

I've added the ref `<MudMenu @ref="Entity.ImageMudMenu">`. In the ViewModle I've added `public MudMenu ImageMudMenu;`. And to the upload Task I've added `ImageMudMenu.CloseMenu();`

Now it works! So, thanks again!